# Closed sets and accumulation points in discrete topology

Tags: general-topology

I am starting to learn topology and I am confused by the basic definitions of closed sets and accumulation points. I am trying to learn from Folland chapter 4. I have an issue with proposition 4.1 in Folland.

I consider the discrete topology on reals $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}))$. Let $A= (0,1] \cup\{3\},$ since $A\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ it is an open set. Now $A^c\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ so it is closed as well. The set of accumulation points of $A$ is $acc(A)=[0,1].$

Proposition 4.1 tells that $A$ is closed only iff $acc(A)\subset A.$ Here in my case $acc(A) \not\subset A$ and $A$ is closed. Is this  not a counter example?

Can some one please explain where my thinking is wrong?

Comment: Lol don't learn from Folland. Learn from Munkres.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that $0$ is not an accumulation point of $(0,1]$. You are using your intuition from the normal topology we have on $\mathbb{R}$, which is not appropriate here. $0$ is not an accumulation point because $\{0\}$ is an open set not intersecting $(0,1]$.

Comment: I used the definition of accumulation point which is given just above proposition Proposition 4.1. Can you please clarify using that definition how $\{0\}$ is not an accumulation point?

Comment: So here $A = (0,1]\cup\{3\}$ and $x = 0$. $U := \{0\}$ is an open neighborhood of $0$. It is clearly not true that $A \cap U\setminus\{x\} \not = \emptyset$ since $U\setminus\{x\} = \emptyset$!

Comment: Ok Now I understand! thanks for the answer!

Comment: Can you please clarify one more thing, It correct to tell in my  case that $acc(A)=\emptyset$ right?

Comment: Yup! The idea is that an accumulation point of $A$ has points of $A$ arbitrarily close to it, but in the discrete topology, nothing is close to each other. This is more easily seen from the fact that the discrete topology is the one obtained from the metric $d(x,y) = 1$ for $x \not = y$ and $d(x,x) = 0$

Comment: Indeed $\operatorname{acc}(A) = \emptyset$ for all $A$ indeed, and so is a subset of any set, which is correct as all subsets are closed.